# Hamachi private Lan minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

Some friends and I set up a private LAN game of minecraft using Hamachi.  We did this so others at school couldn't join.  Someone was still able to join without installing Hamachi and connecting to our network. What have we done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Others could join because even though you are using a VPN connection through Hamachi you still exist in the same network as others, thus they can still connect to you.

There are several ways to do this, the easiest would be to simply change the network you are on on targeted PCs and not tell others about it, then host it (unless your school network is not masquerading this should work).

just go to control panel, under networks and internet select "View network status..." from there select from the left side "change adapter settings", right click on the LAN adapter and double click the ipv4 option.

from there change the IP to something else if one already exists, for example 192.168.20.x (where "x" is between 1 and 254), do the same for the other who you want to join you but change the "x" value for them.

this will put you all on another network that nobody can see unless they join that network first.

**Note**
If you do this there is a big chance you would not be able to use the internet until you put the IPs back as they were.

PC IPs should look like 192.168.x.x OR 10.x.x.x OR 173.(1-37).x.x